# label 'label' type mismatch with previous definition: TOKEN_LABEL!=RULE_LABEL

Tags: antlr4

I noticed that I can't write a rule like this:

```
ausdruck: label=ausdruck 'x' #One
        | label='foo'    #Two
        ;
```

It gives the following error:

> label 'label' type mismatch with previous definition:
>   TOKEN_LABEL!=RULE_LABEL

It looks like this is because once label refers to a parser rule and once to a lexer rule. If I slightly change the rule:

```
ausdruck: label=ausdruck 'x' #One
        | label2='foo'    #Two
        ;
```

Everything works fine.
But why? What is wrong with my first attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've found a bug specific to the use of the `#One` syntax for labeling alternatives.

Each label corresponds to a field with a concrete type in the generated code. The rule `ausdruck` returns `AusdruckContext`, and matching the token `'foo'` returns a `TerminalNode`. These types are not compatible, so normally the label names must be different. However, since you labeled the outer alternatives `#One` and `#Two`, you *should* be able to include labels with the same name in each of the two different contexts.

Comment: Looks like you are right. I filed a bug: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/195

Comment: And I closed the bug (fixed) yesterday :D